# No sound with laptop speakers while have sound with headphone

Tags: sound, 15.10, lenovo, alsa, headphones

I installed Ubuntu 15.10 two weeks ago on Lenovo Z-5070.
From the beginning it played sound and it was okay.

But about one week ago it suddenly it stopped to play sound on my laptop speaker although have sound with headphone. I checked almost everything.

Can any one help me?

P.s : There is no other operating system on my laptop.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, it would recommend using 14.04 LTS version of Ubuntu instead of 15.10. I tried 15.10, and it had so many bugs in my experience whereas with 14.04 I experience no issues at all. Ubuntu website also states that 14.04 is "Recommended for most users" currently.

With 15.10 you can solve this problem by installing **PulseAudio Volume Control** from Ubuntu Software Center. It has a lot of options to choose from, so you can fix this problem and do a lot more good stuff with it.

In application's "Output Devices" tab you can choose a suitable port (usually it will be a choice between headphones and speakers).

If you have more output devices (sound cards), then you can choose default one by pressing green button (device which is not selected will be default, not the opposite).

You can also choose settings per specific application, 1) play music with chosen application 2) and go to "Playback" tab where you can select suitable device for that application and its settings.

Additional option is to choose suitable profile in "Configuration" tab.